# Why do I keep getting module not found in Python anaconda virtual environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I started a conda environment. I tried to run my code however I get the following error:

```
File "aax_trades.py", line 2, in <module>
    import influxdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'influxdb'
```

but I know that the module is actually in my environment because I used the pip under anaconda to download:

```
Requirement already satisfied: influxdb in /home/atom_data/anaconda3/envs/gokce/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.3.0)
```

my path is also set to anaconda.

I literally have the package in the right place and anaconda can't find it. The other stackoverflow questions doesn't answer this. What might be the problem?

Comment: Is your package installed to your main (`base`) conda environment, or the one you created? Also note that it's preferred to use `conda install package` when inside an enviroment to install a package into it, instead of using `pip`.

Comment: conda install package solved my problem